# Installing/Using Phantom.js with Meteor

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

I'm currently struggling with using Phantom.js with a Meteor app of mine.  I have it installed on my local machine (Ubuntu 14.04), it's added to my path (I can run it from my terminal), I also ran and installed the smart wrapper for Phantomjs: `mrt add phantomjs`.

I can see that in my `.meteor > local > build > programs > server > npm` directory there is a `phantomjs` directory.

My question is, how do I actually use Phantom? I'm attempting to scrape from the server side of things. I've tried the following things (using coffeescript):
`phantom = Npm.require "phantomjs"`
`phantom = Npm.require "phantom"`
`phantom = Meteor.require "phantomjs"`
`phantom = Meteor.require "phantom"`

(I've also tried using capital "P's")

All attempts in this way yield: `Error: Cannot find module 'phantomjs'`

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you installing it to use with the spiderable package? If so then it just needs to be on the PATH so it can be used to create pages for bots (more is explained in http://www.manuel-schoebel.com/blog/meteor-and-seo).

Comment: I'n not actually.  I'll just be using it to do some scraping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EDIT] now meteor is supporting npm packages out of the box: https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#installing-npm

---

Here is the procedure for Meteor > 1.0.0

Add the npm package

```
meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

Run meteor to let the npm package to pre-initialise

```
meteor
```

A file packages.json has been created at the root. Edit it to:

```
{
  "phantomjs": "1.9.13"
}
```

To use phantom into your server side code:

```
var phantomJS = Meteor.npmRequire("phantomjs");
```

Bonus: an example of usage (thanks Ben Green), put anywhere in your code:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.startup(function () {
        var phantomjs = Meteor.npmRequire('phantomjs');

        var spawn = Meteor.npmRequire('child_process').spawn;
        Meteor.methods({
            runTest: function (options) {
                command = spawn(phantomjs.path, ['assets/app/phantomDriver.js']);
                command.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
                    console.log('stdout: ' + data);
                });
                command.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
                    console.log('stderr: ' + data);
                });
                command.on('exit', function (code) {
                    console.log('child process exited with code ' + code);
                });
            }
        });

        Meteor.call("runTest");// run the test as soon as meteor server starts
    });
}
```

Create the phantomjs script file `./private/phantomDriver.js` and edit it to

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('http://github.com/', function (){
    console.log('Page Loaded');
    page.render('github.png');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: I think you should create the phantomjs script file inside `/private/phantomDriver.js` instead.

Comment: @MaximusS, assuming I just started the app from my meteor directory, your path is exactly the same as the one I wrote. The leading dot stands for the current working directory which in this case is the meteor app folder. (Not to confuse with a leading dot before a file or directory name which purpose is to hide this last one)

Comment: ah I see. Do you have experience with `spiderable` package by any chance?

Comment: another quick question Flavien. Do you have to add phantom to PATH manually even if you install it this way?

Comment: @MaximusS I am not an expert but I guess meteorhacks:npm will install the package in the same place Meteor.npmRequire('phantomjs'); can retrieve it. If you need your website to be spiderable take a look [here](https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-12-the-complete-guide-to-seo/20). If you need to install everything on a production server (including PhantomJS) go for [MUP](https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up) and an Ubuntu distribution. Or if you feel adventurous, [Docker](https://www.docker.com) + MUP

Comment: "Error: Can't find npm module 'webpage'". what do I do?

Answer (score 3):

The phantomjs wrapper in atmosphere doesn't look like it produces anything that works.

But you can easily add npm packages useing the [npm meteorite package](https://atmospherejs.com/package/npm)

First add the npm package to your project

```
mrt add npm
```

Then add the required phantomjs version to the packages.json file

```
{
     "phantomjs": "1.9.7-6"
}
```

Then use the following code to require the phantomjs npm module:

```
var phantomjs = Meteor.require('phantomjs');
```

Comment: That definitely gets's me own the right track!  I used that method before and was pointing to `phantom` instead of `phantomjs`.  Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome, btw I read in your other comment that you're gonna doe some scraping. Be sure to Check out out cheerio if your scraping static sites that dont load extra stuff with ajax. https://www.npmjs.org/package/cheerio

Comment: ya for scrapping phantom makes it easy but also its much heavier. cheerio and request make the best light combo.