# Meteor: How do you exactly install phantomJS?

Tags: meteor, phantomjs

There isn't a clear guide on how to install Phantom for Meteor, so I decided to ask a question to clarify things.

1. Do you have to install phantom binary in `/usr/local/bin/`? I downloaded a compiled `phantomjs` from the official website and placed inside the above path. I can run `phantomjs` from anywhere now because it's added to path.
2. In addition to 1, do you also have to install it from `meteor npm`? I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23812163/installing-using-phantom-js-with-meteor) to install `"phantomjs": "1.9.13"` as a npm package inside my Meteor app. It gets confusing from here because the binary from the official website is `v2.0.0` while the npm package is `1.9.13`. Do I need to install both?
3. Because of the confusion in 2, I removed `/usr/local/bin/phantomjs` but then I can't run `$phantomjs` anywhere because I don't have anything in `PATH`.

My ultimate goal is to get `spiderable` working. What should I do?

Comment: Well, do you want to use PhantomJS 1.9.8 (npm package 1.9.13 or later) or do you want to use PhantomJS 2? I don't see a 2.0 binary for linux on the official page. I have no idea about spiderable, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the problem was the compiled `phantomjs` binary from the official webpage cannot be used right away in the latest Mac OS, but you have to *unpack* it first. To run `spiderable` package you don't need to do anything other than placing the binary file `phantomjs` inside your local path `/usr/bin/local/`. You can test this by running `$phantomjs` in your terminal. If you see `phantomjs not found` then you haven't installed it. If you see an error `killed 9` then you have the same problem as mine, and you can solve it by following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28267809/phantomjs-getting-killed-9-for-anything-im-trying).

You do not need the `meteorhacks:npm` package.

Comment: For me, the path was `/usr/local/bin` on OSX Yosemite 10.10.3

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two ways:

Method 1:

If you'd like to be able to use PhantomJS via your Meteor app, you would need to use the [Meteorhacks NPM package](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm) and use the latest NPM version [1.9.16 I believe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantomjs).

After that, you can edit your packages.json file to add "phantomjs": "1.9.16", and then reference it via `var phantomjs = Meteor.npmRequire('phantomjs');`

Method 2:

Alternatively, you can use the smart package for [Meteor PhantomJS](https://github.com/gadicc/meteor-phantomjs) and give that a shot.

I personally feel like Method 1 is a better option, as that worked for me. I needed PhantomJS for an app, and that solution worked for me. I haven't tried Method 2 so I can't speak for it, but it looks promising as well.

Give them a shot, and let me know how it goes. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you. Like I mentioned in the question, I already tried method 1 but `spiderable` package complains that `phatnomjs` is not installed, and I assume that's because `phantomjs` is not in `PATH`. How do I address the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a phantomjs wrapper package from atmosphere: https://atmospherejs.com/gadicohen/phantomjs

More importantly here is the spiderable package:
https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/spiderable

I couldn't really answer the questions but more so point ya in a direction that I hope will solve your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal:

`$ meteor npm install --save phantomjs`

In your_meteor_app/server/main.js file (or wherever, provided it's server-side)

`import phantom from 'phantom'`

Answer (score -1):

Just use npm:

```
//Global effect on your machine
```

npm install -g phantomjs

```
//Test if installed
```

npm list -g

```
//Test spiderable working correctly
```

[Test spiderable](http://localhost:3000/?_escaped_fragment_=)

Comment: npm install -g isn't a scalable solution for production apps.